# How to decrease the minimum throughput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, scale, throughput

I need some support on Cosmos DB. I've scaled up a database above 10k RU/s, and now I can no longer come back down to anything below 10k. Looks like I've got locked into a higher tier of some sort, which is very frustrating. I need to go back to what it was before (1,800), but the minimum throughput is now 10,000 and I can't change it. Please help.

[Minimum throughput is stuck in 10,000 RU/s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbIr.png)

Comment: Probably best to contact Azure support. Is there an error, or what happens when trying to enter the new value?

Answer (score 1):

When you scale out Cosmos DB it creates physical partitions that cannot be deallocated. The result is a minimum RU/s that is about 10% of what the maximum throughput ever provisioned was.

The only way now to deal with this is to delete the container. If you have data in the container you need to keep you will need to migrate it to another container. This used to require writing code but there is an easier option now using the [Live Data migrator](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-live-data-migrator). After you copy the data you can then delete the original container.

Update: this is now 1% of max throughput provisioned.

Comment: Hi Mark, curious where this is documented?

Comment: It's 1% rather than 10% https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/set-throughput#current-provisioned-throughput

Comment: Correct, it's 1% now. 2 years ago when I answered this it was 10%. Take a look at the note in this article section here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/scaling-provisioned-throughput-best-practices#general-formula